# Qt/QML: How to activate a Shortcut from C++?

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application which receives input from a serial port and interprets them as key events. The key events are created in C++ and sent to `QGuiApplication::focusWindow()` with `qApp->sendEvent`.

The GUI is implemented in QML and has been handling input through key event handlers. I would like to start using the `Shortcut` QML class to handle cases where I want behavior regardless of which object has focus.

I've discovered that Shortcuts which respond to a real keyboard will not respond to `qApp->sendEvent`, nor do they respond to `qApp->postEvent`.

Getting the behavior I want to reliably occur without Shortcut would be a real pain - is there I way I can handle my synthetic events which will make them visible to Shortcut?

Comment: You are needlessly complicating things. Pass serial data to QML as an emitted signal and process there.QML doesn't really work with C++ events, QML focus is flaky and stiff, I'd recommend implementing your own focus and event dispatch system which either processes events on a global level or forwards them to the objects in focus.

Comment: Give the Shortcut an objectName and get a pointer to it from c++ using qmlEngine->rootObjects().first()->findChild<QQobject*>("shortcutObjName") then send the events to that instead of the focusWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt shortcut objects work through parts of the Qt system which are not part of the regular API, but are exposed to [QPA](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpa.html). Specifically, `QWindowSystemInterface::handleShortcutEvent`, which takes as arguments the current focus window and most of the information encapsulated in a `QKeyEvent`.

```
// A helper to send a QKeyEvent to shortcuts
bool handleShortcutEvent(const QKeyEvent &ev, QWindow *focusWindow) {
    return QWindowSystemInterface::handleShortcutEvent(focusWindow, ev.timestamp(), ev.key(), ev.modifiers(), ev.nativeScanCode(), ev.nativeVirtualKey(), ev.nativeModifiers(), ev.text(), ev.isAutoRepeat(), ev.count());
}
// in my key event generating function
    if(!handleShortcutEvent(event, focusWindow))
        qApp->sendEvent(focusWindow, &event);
```